# EWS SOAP requests - How to get mailbox statistics, folder statistics and permissions from exchange server via EWS using SOAP requests

Tags: go, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am developing a golang application that retrieves from Exchange Server all mailboxes, their statistics, folder statistics and permissions to them. In general I am rewriting a script that applied Get-Mailbox, Get-MailboxFolderStatistics, Get-MailboxStatistics, Get-MailboxPermission and Get-MailboxFolderPermission cmdlets. I was able to get all the mailboxes, but getting the statistics is not working

```golang
bb := []byte(soapStart)
bb = append(bb, []byte("<m:FindMailboxStatisticsByKeywords>\n<m:Mailboxes>\n<t:UserMailbox Id=\""+m.Guid+"\" IsArchive=\"false\"/>\n</m:Mailboxes><t:Keywords>DisplayName</t:Keywords></m:FindMailboxStatisticsByKeywords>")...)
bb = append(bb, []byte(soapEnd)...)
//bb := []byte(soapStart)
//bb = append(bb, []byte("<m:GetNonIndexableItemDetails>\n         <m:Mailboxes>\n            <t:LegacyDN>"+m.ReferenceId+"</t:LegacyDN>\n         </m:Mailboxes>\n         <m:SearchArchiveOnly>false</m:SearchArchiveOnly>\n      </m:GetNonIndexableItemDetails>")...)
//bb = append(bb, []byte(soapEnd)...)
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", c.GetEWSAddr(), bytes.NewReader(bb))
if err != nil {
    return
}
defer req.Body.Close()
dump, err := httputil.DumpRequestOut(req, true)
fmt.Printf("Request:\n%v\n----\n", string(dump))

req.SetBasicAuth(c.GetUsername(), options.GetString("pwd", ""))
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "text/xml")

client := &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
       return http.ErrUseLastResponse
    },
}
client.Transport = ntlmssp.Negotiator{}
http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}

resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
if err != nil {
    return
}
dump, err = httputil.DumpResponse(resp, true)
fmt.Printf("Response:\n%v\n----\n", string(dump))
```

Request:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="ppth:\\www.w3.org\2001\XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="ptth:\\schemas.microsoft.com\exchange\services\2006\messages" xmlns:t="ptth:\\schemas.microsoft.com\exchange\services\2006\types" xmlns:soap="ptth:\\schemas.xmlsoap.org\soap\envelope\">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
<m:FindMailboxStatisticsByKeywords>
    <m:Mailboxes>
        <t:UserMailbox Id="existing id here" IsArchive="false"/>
    </m:Mailboxes>
    <t:Keywords>
        <string>DisplayName</string>
    </t:Keywords></m:FindMailboxStatisticsByKeywords>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

(also i did same request without element Keywords)

and i got that Response:

```xml
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 10 Oct 2023 12:24:22 GMT
Request-Id: idHere
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=cookie; expires=Thu, 10-Oct-2024 12:24:23 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-BackEndCookie=cookie; expires=Thu, 09-Nov-2023 12:24:23 GMT; path=/EWS; HttpOnly
X-Aspnet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Beserver: myServer
X-Calculatedbetarget: serveraddress
X-Diaginfo: myServer
X-Feserver: myServer
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
2f7
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="ptth:\\schemas.xmlsoap.org\soap\envelope\"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="ptth:\\schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorInternalServerError</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="ru-RU">Internal server error. Failed to execute the operation.</faultstring><detail><e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorInternalServerError</e:ResponseCode><e:Message xmlns:e="ptth:\\schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">Internal server error. Failed to execute the operation.</e:Message></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
0
```

And i check error on exchange server:

```
Exception processing. Exception information: System.NullReferenceException: The object reference does not point to an instance of the object.
   in Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.FindMailboxStatisticsByKeywords.SaveRequestData(FindMailboxStatisticsByKeywordsRequest request)
   in Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.FindMailboxStatisticsByKeywords..ctor(ICallContext callContext, FindMailboxStatisticsByKeywordsRequest request)
   in Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.FindMailboxStatisticsByKeywordsRequest.GetServiceCommand(ICallContext callContext)
   in Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.BaseRequest.InitializeServiceCommand(ICallContext callContext)
   in Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.ServiceTask`1..ctor(BaseRequest request, ICallContext callContext, ServiceAsyncResult`1 serviceAsyncResult)
   in Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.BaseRequest.CreateServiceTask[T](ICallContext callContext, ServiceAsyncResult`1 serviceAsyncResult)
   in Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.BaseRequest.CreateTask[T](ICallContext callContext, ServiceAsyncResult`1 serviceAsyncResult)
   in Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Core.Types.BaseRequest.Submit[T](ICallContext callContext, AsyncCallback hostCallback, Object hostState)
   in Microsoft.Exchange.Services.Wcf.EWSService.BeginFindMailboxStatisticsByKeywords(FindMailboxStatisticsByKeywordsSoapRequest soapRequest, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   in AsyncInvokeBeginBeginFindMailboxStatisticsByKeywords(Object , Object[] , AsyncCallback , Object )
   in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.AsyncMethodInvoker.InvokeBegin(Object instance, Object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does your SOAP request really have `ptth` and backslashes (instead of forward ones) in all the URLs in all the XML namespace definitions? I mean, I woule expect these URLs to read something like `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org` and so on.

Comment: [Here](https://go.dev/play/p/3YcMddJZkGR) is one way you can produce the XML _almost_ as you need using `encoding/xml` and custom data types, and under the assumption you need correct namespaces. The difference is that in your example `<string>` element is not qualified by a namespace, and in mine it would get qualified with `http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types`.

Comment: And [here](https://go.dev/play/p/qzHiZodbY7I) is one way to produce an XML document which is 100% like what's intended which is less universal but is arguably a bit more convenient to use. Again, this is done under the assumptions the namespaces should be sensible.

Comment: …to clear up why I asked about those `xmlns` URIs: these XML namespaces make names of XML elements fully qualified (by these namespaces), and the parser on the receiving end supposedly expects to parse out these fully-qualified elements from the request, and since it does not "see" them there–due to bogus URIs–it supposedly constructs an invalid object representing your request, with some of its fields being `null`, wich then blows up on futher processing (so you might have likely found a bug in some component of your Exchange server).

Comment: i wrote "ppth" and "\" instead of "http" and "/" because stackoverflow told me my question looks like spam, i think it`s some bug.

Comment: Next time, state that clearly in the question right away so those who are to answer do not second-guess and and spend time thinking about hypotheses based on false premises.

Comment: now the error on exchange server is NotImplementedException, I read this method FindMailboxStatisticsByKeywords only works with exchange server 2016+ versions. I don't understand how to get mailbox statistics in earlier versions (I have 2013).

Comment: The articles on `Mailboxes` and `Keywords` elements of `FindMailboxStatisticsByKeywords` linked [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/findmailboxstatisticsbykeywords) say these elements were introduced in v2013. Since _nested_ elements cannot be introduced earlier than the parent, I'm inclined to think it should be supported in 2013.

Comment: I think, this question supposedly has no more to do with programming in Go (unless you really generate an XML document which the server does not understand, and it roots in mishandling of XML in Go), so I would say you'd better ask your question [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/342/office-exchange-server-management).

Comment: Also be aware that Microsoft has announced the end of EWS in Exchange Online so this is a dead end solution:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/retirement-of-exchange-web-services-in-exchange-online/ba-p/3924440